How to express a function with several inputs: $f(n), f(n,x)$ or $f(n,x,G)$
I want to express a function, but it is a little unorthodox. Basically it has several inputs. It has $n$ expressing the position in the sequence and $x$ describing the initial condition where $n=0$. However, it also has $G$ expressing a specific group we are working with, but this $G$ will not change.
$
f(n)=
\begin{cases}
 x&\text{if}\, x=0\\
 f(n-1)G&\text{if}\, x\geq 1
\end{cases}
$
However, I don't think I can just write this function as $f(n)$ as this does not specify:

The initial condition $x$
The group $G$

However, the initial variable and $G$ are specified in the definition of the function, so perhaps $f(n)$ suffices?
Or, perhaps I should write $f(n,x)$ as $x$ and $n$ will both vary depending on our input, but $G$ will remain the same for every case?
Or, finally, should I use $f(n,x,G)$, but this looks odd?

My personal approach:  "Fixed" parameters, like $G$, appear as subscripts.  Variables should be arguments.  I'm not entirely sure what $x$ is in your discussion, by reading it as an active variable I'd write $f_G(x,n)$.  The alternative, if you really are thinking of this as a function of $n$ alone, would be $f_{G,x}(n)$.   To stress:  I'm not claiming this sort of notation is universal, though I certainly think it is common.

Your formula for $f(n)$ has conditions on $x$. Are they supposed to be conditions on $n$? Assuming so, I would agree with lulu, with the additional comment that one can also say "If $G$ is understood from context, we will simply write $f_x(n)$; if both $G$ and $x$ are clear from context, we will simply write $f(n)$."
